# Row mean of two matching columns with same name but differ by: '_1' and '_2'

Tags: r

Lets say I have the dataframe:

```
z = data.frame(col_1 = c(1,2,3,4), col_2 = c(3,4,5,6))

  col_1 col_2
1     1     3
2     2     4
3     3     5
4     4     6
```

I want to take columns with the same name that only differ by the number e.g. '_1' and '_2' and take the pairwise mean. In reality I have a big dataframe with many pairs and they are not in a nice order, therefore looking for a clever solution that can be applied to this.

So the output should look like this:

```
  col
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
```

With the column name given as the same as the column pair but with the additional label removed.

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: So there are other columns called `abc_1, ... abc_n` and `xyz_1, ...` all of which are numeric?

Comment: Yes, all of the columns are numeric but they only have pairs (so n =2). They are measures that were taken at the beginning and at the end of an experiment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a base R option using `list2DF` + `split.default` + `rowMeans`

```
list2DF(lapply(split.default(z,gsub("_\\d+","",names(z))),rowMeans))
```

which gives

```
  col
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, this works really nicely. Could you explain the `"_\\d+"` in gsub. I realised in my dataset I actually didn't have underscores but simply `col1` and `col2` but your solution still worked using `"\\d+"` in gsub instead.

Comment: @DylanDijk `\\d+` matches the pattern of multiple successive digits, e.g., `0-9`. Here is a link to regex in R, hope it can help.https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Try this `tidyverse` approach. By using `separate()` you can extract the name and then with reshaping you can reach the desired output. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Data
z = data.frame(col_1 = c(1,2,3,4), col_2 = c(3,4,5,6))
#Code
z1 <- z %>% mutate(id=1:n()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  separate(name,c('var1','var2'),sep='_') %>%
  group_by(id,var1) %>% summarise(Mean=mean(value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = var1,values_from=Mean) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-id)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 1
    col
  <dbl>
1     2
2     3
3     4
4     5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `purrr` oriented solution:

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
split.default(z, str_remove(names(z), "[:digit:]+$")) %>% map_dfc(rowMeans)

#> # A tibble: 4 x 1
#>   col_
#>   <dbl>
#> 1     2
#> 2     3
#> 3     4
#> 4     5
```

It works even if z is:

```
z <- data.frame(col_1 = c(1,2,3,4),
                col_2 = c(3,4,5,6),
                anothercol_1 = c(1,2,3,4),
                anothercol_2 = c(3,4,5,6))
```